# JQuery Accordion Menu Flashes When Loading

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

I implemented a Jquery menu on a site, but whenever I click on a new page, the menu drops down for a second then goes back to normal. Does anyone know why this is?

Here is the link: http://www.knowledgecity.com/alj/
Click on the first menu item "Act Pragmatically", then click on the first item in that menu. As the new page loads, the menu will move a bit. Try it in IE.

thank you in advance for your help.

David

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to hide your accordion content then show when calling accordion. This will prevent the flicking that you see.

example

**CSS**

```
#element{
 display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#element').accordion().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your div holding the horizontal "Prida | Business | Computer" menu, you could add a nested div and give it a fixed height with css. It's acting jumpy because after the DOM loads, this menu is just a text list. Styles are then injected in to your code and finally applied to the menu.

Currently you have:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul> ... </ul>
</div>
```

I would try:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="tabsContainer" style="height:42px">
        <ul> ... </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, stick a div with a fixed height in to one of your `<li>` elements:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><div style="height:42px"></div>...</li>
        ... 
    </ul>
</div>
```